# Update Viewpager items in Particular Page

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager

I want to get the new list each time and update the view when viewpager in particular position.I tried below way but it was lagging more.I update my list in first page and i get those updated results in 3 page.so i need to get the new results everytime on this 3 page and update the viewpager.Any sugg pls

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            check=position;
            if(position==3) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        recentList=new ArrayList<PlayerModel>();
                        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(MultHomePageActivity.this);
                        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
                        Cursor mFavoritesCursor = mySQLiteAdapter.fetchRecentData(AppConstants.AUDIO_TABLE);
                        LogUtil.error("Count",mFavoritesCursor.getCount()+"-->");
                        if(mFavoritesCursor!=null)
                            recentList= getAudioFavRecentsList(mFavoritesCursor);
                        mySQLiteAdapter.close();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                        }
                });



            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

I have tried to put my code in separate thread like this.still it was lagging

```
    private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String resp;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        recentList=new ArrayList<PlayerModel>();
        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(MultHomePageActivity.this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
        Cursor mFavoritesCursor = mySQLiteAdapter.fetchRecentData(AppConstants.AUDIO_TABLE);
        LogUtil.error("Recent Count",mFavoritesCursor.getCount()+"-->");
        if(mFavoritesCursor!=null)
            recentList= getAudioFavRecentsList(mFavoritesCursor);
        mySQLiteAdapter.close();
        adapter.setFragment(fragmentMultCards.newInstance(recentList,AppConstants.
                AUDIO_PLAYER,AppConstants.RECENT_PLAYER),3,getString(R.string.msg_recents));

        return resp;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
    }
}

    private List<PlayerModel> getAudioFavRecentsList(Cursor mAudioCursor) {
    List<PlayerModel> cursorList=new ArrayList<>();
    if (mAudioCursor != null) {
        if(mAudioCursor.getCount()>0)
            do{

                cursorList.add(new PlayerModel(
                        mAudioCursor.getInt(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_ID)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_DISPLAY_NAME)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_SIZE)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_DATE_TAKEN)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_DURATION)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_ALBUM)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_ALBUM_ID)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_ARTIST)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_COMPOSER)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_DATA)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_TRACK)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_MIME)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_IS_ALARAM)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_BOOKMARK)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_TITLE)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_IS_NOTIFICATION)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_IS_MUSIC)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_RECENT_DATE)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_FAVORITE)),
                        mAudioCursor.getString(mAudioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AppConstants.KEY_AUDIO))

                ));

            }while (mAudioCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return cursorList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fetch your data in separate thread and once you will get data then you will update it. For now you are fetching data in Main Thread that's why its lagging.
I hope it will works for you :)

Comment: Can u explain it with example pls

Comment: I updated my qn pls check it.I tried AsyncTask still my page was lagging.